# JQuery extend events to new objects of a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery, I can assign function to events of a given selector by:

```
$(selector).click(function { /*something*/ });
```

However, this will only apply to current existing objects that satisfy the `selector` criteria.

Now, assume we have in our application an external plugin or library that we can't or we don't want to modify, but it generates new items that satisfy the `selector` criterion with the user interation.

For simplicity, assume we have an external plugin that creates new elements of class `.something` when the users clicks on a button.

Is there a way a way, in Javascript or JQuery, to add a `.click` listener to all the existing and future elements of class `.something`??

I mean, I could add another `.click` function to the button, and everytime it adds one class, find it and add the new listener to it. But would it be a way to make new elements of a given class to somehow inherit that listener?

Comment: Yes. There is. But it's really hard to understand what you want to do.....

Comment: Isn't this what you want? `$('.something').click(function { /*something*/ });`

Comment: Do you have parent element with  an id? If so find the the children of that parent...

Comment: Yes, but there is an external plugin that creates new elements of class `something` after I have assigned the listener to the current existing ones. I can't add a callback to know whenever the external plugin creates a new element, so I was wondering if there was a way so that the new elements will inherit the listeners.

Comment: $('#parent').children() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.live()` is depreciated (aka dont use it for newer version so jQuery), use

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

instead.  this will take into account pre-existing and dynamically added dom elements. see example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
        $('body').append(clone);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="add">Add Button</a>

<button class="btn" id="template">Alert Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `on` method for event delegation.

```
$('body').on('click', '.mynewobject', function() {
    // do this and that
});
```

Edit: Stupid me, forgot the selector quotes in the first place.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, you are incorrect. this is in fact a solution. Imperative is correct in his/her suggestion, he/she just did not explain the answer. this does not deserve a downvote. lol and bhoj, how can you say you know what the OP wants when all your comments in the question are off base and wild guesses.  OP wants to know if he/she can apply bindings to pre-existing and added dom elements. that is the issue and this answer addresses it.

Comment: It is in fact a solution. It worked for me with `$(document)` instead of `$(body)`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your saying that an element is being added to the DOM via user interaction.  For such instances, where say  didn't exist when the DOM was loaded but then a user clicks and then that ELEMENT is added to the page, what you will need to use is the JQUERY function **.live()**

**Example:**

> $( "#selector" ).live( "click", function() {   alert( "This will now
>   work." ); // jQuery 1.3+ });

The JQUERY LIVE function is needed for any elements that are created after the DOM is loaded the first time.

Comment: fyi: live is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

See the document:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

It says:
Attach an event handler for all elements which *match the current selector, now and in the **future***. Though it was deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9.

You can try
http://api.jquery.com/on/
instead